# AspectJ compile issues, java8 lambda expression, switch statement

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, aop, aspectj

I am trying to use aspectJ to do AOP programming.
But AJC compiler throw errors below, javac compiler works perfectly.

```
Error:(19, 0) ajc: The method getKey() is undefined for the type Object
Error:(19, 0) ajc: The method getValue() is undefined for the type Object
Error:(22, 0) ajc: Cannot refer to the static enum field ApplicationType.transport within an initializer
Error:(25, 0) ajc: Cannot refer to the static enum field ApplicationType.exposure within an initializer
Error:(28, 0) ajc: Cannot refer to the static enum field ApplicationType.manufacture within an initializer
Error:(31, 0) ajc: Cannot refer to the static enum field ApplicationType.factoryhub within an initializer
```

My source file is Maps.java ApplicationType.java --

```
public class Maps {
    public static <K, V> Map<K, V> toMap(Map.Entry<K, V>... entries) {
        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(
          Stream
            .of(entries)
             // compile error The method getKey() is undefined for the type Object
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey(), e -> e.getValue())));
    }
}
ApplicationType.java 
public enum ApplicationType {

    transport(0),
    exposure(1),
    manufacture(2),
    factoryhub(3);

    private int code;

    ApplicationType(int code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    ApplicationType(String application) {
        for (ApplicationType value : values()) {
            if (value.name().equals(application)) {
                switch (value) {
//ajc: Cannot refer to the static enum field ApplicationType.transport within an initializer
                    case transport:
                        setCode(0);
                        break;
                    case exposure:
                        setCode(1);
                        break;
                    case manufacture:
                        setCode(2);
                        break;
                    case factoryhub:
                        setCode(3);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(int code) {
        this.code = code;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fix for**

```
Error:(19, 0) ajc: The method getKey() is undefined for the type Object
Error:(19, 0) ajc: The method getValue() is undefined for the type Object
```

Reason for above errors is aspectj unable to discover the type of `.toMap` result. Lambda expressions are evaluated lazily whenever a collect operation is performed. To fix the error, see the variation of the code below. Store the results of `.toMap` operation explicitly and then user `Collections.unmodifiableMap`

```
public static <K, V> Map<K, V> toMap(final Map.Entry<K, V>... entries) {
    Map<K, V> map = Stream.of(entries).collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
    return Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);
}
```

**Fix for:**

```
Error:(22, 0) ajc: Cannot refer to the static enum field ApplicationType.transport within an initializer
```

Overloaded constructor `Application(String name)` for enum looks incorrect. You can simplify your enum code as shown below to get rid of error.

```
public enum ApplicationType {
    transport(0),
    exposure(1),
    manufacture(2),
    factoryhub(3);

    private int code;

    ApplicationType(int code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public static ApplicationType parse(String name) {
        return ApplicationType.valueOf(name.toLowerCase());
    }

    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }
}
```

I have added a `parse` method in case you want the enum back based on `name`.

Hope this helps.